# Is there a possibility that a firestore onUpdate trigger change parameter chnage.after.data() and change.before.data() be null or undefined?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Here is my cloud function

```
exports.onUpdateEvent = functions.firestore.document('collection/{documentId}')
.onUpdate((change, context) => {
    const after: FirebaseFirestore.DocumentData = change.after.data();
    const before: FirebaseFirestore.DocumentData = change.before.data();
})
```

Is there a possibility that after or before have null or undefined in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the fields can come as null, one way this can happen is that the data to be evaluated does not yet exist, in the official [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) it is recommended to evaluate the data against a possible null value, for example:

```
  // Get an object with the current document value.
  // If the document does not exist, it has been deleted.
  const document = change.after.exists ? change.after.data() : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is unfortunately incorrect. onUpdate is only called when the document has been modified, so the data must exist. onWrite is the function you need to check .exists against.

Read the documentation that Harif linked, https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#function_triggers.